# Visualizing results of an aggregate function query

Tags: postgis, postgresql, carto

I want to visualize the results of an aggregate function in CartoDB. For example I want to understand and visualize the top 20 owners of land by acres with the following query.  As single owner often owns many parcels, so an aggregate function is required.  I do the following query to return a list of owners and the summed value of the acres.

```
SELECT owner, SUM(acres) as totalacres 

FROM owner_types 

WHERE county ='Monterey County' and detailed_ownership_type = 'company'
GROUP BY owner 
ORDER BY totalacres DESC LIMIT 20
```

Now, I want to create a map that visualizes the location of all of the polygons associated with the owners generated by the above query.  I have tried a subquery like such:

```
       SELECT * FROM owner_types
       WHERE owner =
           (SELECT owner, SUM(acres) as totalacres 

FROM owner_types 

WHERE county ='Monterey County' and detailed_ownership_type = 'company'
GROUP BY owner 
ORDER BY totalacres DESC LIMIT 20)
```

But I am violating some subquery rules including more than one column and aggregate functions within subqueries.  Can someone guide me to the best way to match the owner values of the first query with their original geometries to make a new map?

Comment: You don't need the sum in the subquery, you are joining on owner, after all, and not using the sum in the outer select. If you change the = to IN then this  query should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** JUST saw this was for CartoDB, but you should be able to get the gist of it with this solution...

If you join the owner by acres SUM table to the original owners table, you can add the geometry from the owners table to the summed acreage... and by wrapping that in a create table statement, you can take advantage of the default 'with OID's' that postgres will use, and build a new spatial table in PostGIS.

I think it would go something like this:

```
create table OwnerByAcres as (
  SELECT 
    owntype.* --includes geometry
  , ownacres.totalacres --summed acreage

  FROM owner_types as owntype
           JOIN   
   (  SELECT owner
        , SUM(acres) as totalacres 
    FROM owner_types 
WHERE county ='Monterey County' and detailed_ownership_type = 'company'
GROUP BY owner 
ORDER BY totalacres DESC LIMIT 20

) AS ownacres on owntype.owner = ownacres.owner

)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is  a workable solution.  The unique issue of cartodb here is that "create Table"  makes an invisible table that can be called, but won't appear in your dashboard unless you supply the appropriate : [extra work](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/wiki/creating-tables-though-the-SQL-API)

Comment: @AdamC ok great! Glad it worked!!!